# Issues in saving bulk data in HBase in Pseudo-distributed mode

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hive, hdfs

I am setting up CDH4 in a pseudo-distributed mode.

I have set up Hadoop, and as suggested on CDH4 installation guide, have also completed the hdfs demo successfully.

I have also set up, HIVE, & HBase.

To populate the data in Hbase, I have written a java client, which populates the bulk data in HBase (around 1M rows each in 4 tables).

Now I am facing two issues:

1. When java client is running to port the dummy data into hbase, the regionserver shut down after around 4,50,000 rows of data is entered in total.
2. Using Hive, I am not able to access tables created in HBase, or worst, even cannot create tables from hive shell. Though, the hbase shell shows me the data/table structure (whetever has been generated before regionserver shut down.)

I have seen other posts regarding same. Seems that the 2nd issue is related to my /etc/hosts or hive-site.xml. Thus, I am pasting contents of both of them.

***/etc/hosts***

```
198.251.79.225 u17162752.onlinehome-server.com u17162752
198.251.79.225 default-domain.com
198.251.79.225 hbase.zookeeper.quorum localhost
198.251.79.225     cloudera-vm     # Added by NetworkManager
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
127.0.1.1       cloudera-vm-local localhost
```

***hive-site.xml***

```
<configuration>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore</value>
  <description>the URL of the MySQL database</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>hive</value>
</property>


<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>mypassword</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
  <value>thrift://127.0.0.1:9083</value>
  <description>IP address (or fully-qualified domain name) and port of the metastore     host</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.support.concurrency</name>
  <description>Enable Hive's Table Lock Manager Service</description>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.zookeeper.quorum</name>
  <description>Zookeeper quorum used by Hive's Table Lock Manager</description>
  <value>zk1.myco.com,zk2.myco.com,zk3.myco.com</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
  <description>Zookeeper quorum used by Hive's Table Lock Manager</description>
  <value>zk1.myco.com,zk2.myco.com,zk3.myco.com</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
  <value>NOSASL</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

These issue are holding me from accomplish the task, I am supposed to.

Thanks in advance
Abhiskek

PS: This is my first post to this forum, so apologies, for anything inappropriate, you might have found! Thanks for bearing with me.

Hi Tariq, Thanks for your response. I have somehow managed to get over this. Now, I am facing another issue.

I am having 4 tables in HBase already, for which I want to create external tables in hive shell. But on running create external table commands on hive shell gives following error:

```
'ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: No server address listed in -ROOT- for region .META.,,1.1028785192 containing row'
```

Also, this error appears when I do something in HBase shell.

The other error that comes with the former one, on hbase shell is related to zookeeper. Stacktrace:

```
'WARN zookeeper.ZKUtil: catalogtracker-on-    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation@6a9a56bf-    0x1413718482c0010 Unable to get data of znode /hbase/unassigned/1028785192
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$SessionExpiredException: KeeperErrorCode = Session     expired for /hbase/unassigned/1028785192'
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Showing the logs will be helpful.

Comment: Hi Tariq, Thanks for your response. I have somehow managed to get over this. Now, I am facing another issue.

I am having 4 tables in HBase already, for which I want to create external tables in hive shell. But on running create external table commands on hive shell gives following error:

ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: No server address listed in -ROOT- for region .META.,,1.1028785192 containing row

Comment: did you figure out the issue yet?